# Generate Shortcodes by Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, theme-development, shortcode

Check this code:

```
function slide_group() {                    
        register_taxonomy('Group', 'slides', array(
           'hierarchical' => true /*visualizza come le categorie*/, 'label' => 'Group',
           'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true));}
     add_action('init', 'slide_group', 0);


function square_slider_template() {

            // Query Arguments
            $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'slides',
                        'posts_per_page'    => 5
                    );  

            // The Query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // Check if the Query returns any posts
            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            // Start the Slider ?>
            <div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">

                    <?php       
                    // The Loop
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li>

                        <?php // Check if there's a Slide URL given and if so let's a link to it
                        if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'square_slideurl', true) != '' ) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'square_slideurl', true ) ); ?>">
                        <?php }

                        // The Slide's Image
                        echo the_post_thumbnail();

                        // Close off the Slide's Link if there is one
                        if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'square_slideurl', true) != '' ) { ?>
                            </a>
                        <?php } ?>

                        </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                </ul><!-- .slides -->
            </div><!-- .flexslider -->

            <?php }

            // Reset Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }

    // Slider Shortcode

        function square_slider_shortcode() {
            ob_start();
            square_slider_template();
            $slider = ob_get_clean();
            return $slider;
        }
        add_shortcode( 'slider', 'square_slider_shortcode' );
```

This code is creating a slider based on "slider" custom post type using the thumbnail image. I created a custom taxonomy too. 
What I would do is create a "foreach" loop based on the taxonomy-term that create a shortcode with the taxonomy-term name ( [design], [develop] etc.. OR [slider type=design], [slider type=develop] ) that contain only the posts of the taxonomy_term. 
For example, [design] contains/displays only the post with design taxonomy, [develop] contains/displays only the post with develop taxonomy etc.

## EDIT/UPDATE #2

I'm at this step:

```
    function square_slider_shortcode( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
                        'type'      => '00', // default type
                    ), $atts, 'square_slider' );

    // Sanitize input:
    $pid = sanitize_title( $atts['type'] );

    // Output
    return square_slider_template( $pid );    
}

add_shortcode( 'slider', 'square_slider_shortcode' );

function square_slider_template( $pid = '' )
{
$args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'slides',
    'p'           => $pid,


);  ?>

<?php
    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Check if the Query returns any posts
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    // Start the Slider ?>
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">

            <?php       
            // The Loop
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++):
                    $num_slide="slide_" . $i;
                    $slide = get_field($num_slide);
                    ?>                                      
                    <?php if (!empty($slide)): ?><li><img src="<?php echo $slide; ?>"></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endfor; ?> 
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ul><!-- .slides -->
    </div><!-- .flexslider -->

    <?php }

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

I solved in this way, I create a loop with the slides and I'll create the slider. It's not a smart way or the proper way, but it works :) 
UPDATE: everything works but the slider appear **always** at the top of the page, independently of the position inside the editor. 
I tried to put it inside another shortcode like `[one_third][slider type="98"][/one_third][one_third_last]casual words[/one_third_last]` but it appear outside the div tag like you can see in the image
[image]

Comment: why not just a single shortcode that you pass the term name to as an attribute?

Comment: Regarding the update, you should rename `$type` to `$pid` for clarity. The `square_slider_template` function should return something or you can use the output buffer to catch it's output. Also consider using `posts_per_page` to control the number of slides. You should then try to feed the  `get_field()` function with the corresponding post id: `get_field($field_name, $post_id )`, to see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4):

You want to define a potentially  huge number of different shortcodes with the **same** shortcode callback?

Why don't you define a *single* shortcode, with a term attribute? For example

```
[sc term="london"]
```

*ps:*

I think your problem lies in the `$tax_term->name` part, which could be a string like *City of London* and that's not a valid shortcode name. Try `$tax_term->slug` instead, but I don't think it's a good strategy!

Another problem is that you are defining a function inside the foreach loop. That should give you an error like: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare examples_shortcode() ...`.

You should consider using `WP_DEBUG` in your developement. [Here's](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) a good starting point.

### Update:

You could use for example:

```
function square_slider_shortcode( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
                        'type'      => 'sport', // default type
                        'nr'        => 5,       // default number of slides
                    ), $atts, 'square_slider' );

    // Sanitize input:
    $type = sanitize_title( $atts['type'] );
    $nr   = (int) $atts['nr'];

    // Output
    return square_slider_template( $type, $nr );    
}

add_shortcode( 'slider', 'square_slider_shortcode' );
```

where:

```
function square_slider_template( $type = '', $nr = 5 )
{
    // Query Arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type'       => 'slides',
        'posts_per_page'  => $nr,
        'tax_query'       => array(
             array(
                'taxonomy' => 'slides',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $type,
             ),
        ),      
    );  

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // ... etc ...

    return $html;
}
```

Then your shortcode syntax would be:

```
[slider type="sport" nr="5"]
```

where you now can change the *term* (`type`) and the *number of slides* (`nr`) to your needs.

Comment: I added more info to explain better what I would do :)
btw, what do you mean like "attribute"? I'm still a noob in php :)

Comment: The shortcode attributes make it more flexible. If you define your shortcode to handle a attribute called for example `type`, then you can then use it like  `[slider type="sport"]` or `[slider type="news"]`.

Comment: but does it works with taxonomies? (look above, I added my entire code )

Comment: I updated the answer with a demo that you can extend further.

Comment: @dborghez Did you manage to use this for your slides?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was very busy so I didn't dedicate time to try! I'll tell you something asap :)

Comment: Please don't kill me but I took some time to think about that and I conclude that imho it's smarter using every custom post like a slider (and create shortcodes with "extract", using the pageID like [slider type="pageID"] ) and add in the post some metaboxes to add slide and than use the imgs inside the metaboxes.
What do you think about that? Which one do you think is smarter and easier? And please sorry if I'm changing my mind after your update!

Comment: ok ;-) You can always modify the shortcode attribute to your needs. Don't use `extract`, it's a bad practice. There are many ways to implement a slider shortcode. Pros/Cons to both methods you describe, so choose the one that suit your needs.  Another way would be to use the attached images to the post.

Comment: Soo, I've just installed Advanced Custom Field to create the structure, then I'll try to create the shortcodes. I'll tell you at the end if I was able or if I smashed my mac against the wall :)

Comment: hehe, ok ACF is great, good luck with that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a seft-closing shortcode.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API will be a great read to get started.